# Excel 2013 - PowerPivot Add-Ins : error with "MetConv.txt" file

Tags: converters, measurement, powerpivot, excel-2013, office-2013

```
OS : Windows 7
Excel : 2013 Version 15.0.4535.1003
```

I have an issue with Excel 2013
When I select `"Options" > "Add-Ins"`, the following message appears :

```
"Measurement Converter. An error has occured in MetConv.txt file! Please view the MetConv.log file for more information"
```

There is no error message in MetConv.log file.

My MetConv.txt file is here :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Smart Tag
```

Because of that error I can't open an PowerPivot Datamodel with Measures.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think your MS office not installed properly. try to reinstall this and use the admin account for installation if not before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues.

If not needed you can try to disable the feature
File->Options->Proofing->AutoCorrect Options->Actions
Measurement Converter

If you want to fix the problem try to uninstall the feature (Programs -> Office -> Change [How to chance an Office installation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/install-or-remove-individual-office-programs-and-components-HA001234067.aspx)) and remove the Measurement Converter there. Try to reinstall it after a reebot.. did the trick for me.